# Identify damage and scratches on packages

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I am working on a project to identify damages and scratches to the packages while they move through different legs of transport.

Is there a way to detect damages and scratches by just using the OpenCV library and not diving into Neural Networks, ML, etc? At this point, we are mainly concerned with results and we don't care about accuracy. We can even work with algorithms that require a special environment for their proper functioning (eg: light, camera angle, etc)

I tried web search but most of the articles take me to neural network models which are not what we are trying to explore at this stage of our project.

Comment: Without seeing typical samples, no answer will make sense.

Comment: I believe you cannot make sure projects without diving into NN and ML.